# Can i use 5v 3amp. in Raspberry Pi3 B+

Tags: pi-3, hardware

i am using Raspberry Pi3 B+ and i am in a confusion that can i use 5 volt, 3 ampare adaptor in my Pi?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Pi will only draw the current (amps) that it needs. Recommended minimum is 2.5 amps.

Its best to have a hard wired power lead with large diameter cable (official PSU has 18AWG cable).